# How to make nova service state down for test purpose without shutting down node?

Tags: virtual-machine, openstack, openstack-nova, novaclient

I am testing `nova evacuate` command. I have 2 compute nodes and one of them has a running vm. I want to evacuate vm from one node to another and for that I need `nova-compute` service's state `down` on the host where vm is running now. I know I can achieve that by shutting down host node. But I don't want to shut down any node. I found commands to disable `nova-compute` service or delete `nova-compute` service but could not find for making state down of `nova-compute` service. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are new request method added in 2.11 microversion for services - force-down

It will change the state for hypervisor from UP to down.
See the [docs](http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/nova.html#nova-service-force-down)

Note: if you change the state all VM will migrate by themselves